# How to create a Gantt chart [VBA] using cell borders

Tags: excel, vba, date, gantt-chart

I would like to have a gantt style chart in my project by adding in VBA border to specific cells like here:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/XqkKJxw]

I tried with this script :

```
Public Sub DisegnaLineeGantt(ByVal riga As Long)

  Dim DataInizio, DataFine As Date
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim ultimaColonna As Long
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim rng2 As Range

  Set rng = Range(Cells(15, 11), Cells(15, ultimaColonna))
  Set rng2 = Range(Cells(riga, 11), Cells(riga, ultimaColonna))
  rng2.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
  DataInizio = Cells(riga, 3)
  DataFine = Cells(riga, 4)
  ultimaColonna = Worksheets("Commesse").Columns.Count

  For Each cell In rng
    If DataInizio = cell Then
      Cells(riga, cell.Column).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      Cells(riga, cell.Column).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      Cells(riga, cell.Column).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
    ElseIf DataFine = cell Then
      Cells(riga, cell.Column).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      Cells(riga, cell.Column).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      Exit For
    ElseIf DataInizio < cell And DataFine > cell Then
      Cells(riga, cell.Column).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So, did your script work?

Comment: Not well, it is slow and sometimes happens that it doesn't correspond to the dates.

Comment: You give a value to `ultimaColonna` *after* you set `rng` and `rng2`. Also, when you use `Worksheets("Commesse").Columns.Count` you end up with a huge number, try `ultimacolonna = Worksheets("Commesse").UsedRange.Columns.Count` instead

Comment: Ok i found solution. The Cells(riga, cell.Column).Borders.Weight = xlMedium was causing the problem, now i will search for another way to add border.